# Mochiweb custom configuration

Tags: web, erlang, mochiweb

I have tried to search for an answer in google, and this site, but it seems I cannot find anywhere, so I decided to ask.

I'm planning of using mochiweb as my webserver, and I studied it for few days now.
My question is simple:

Where could I put or add a custom configuration? (e.g. Database connection setting), so mochiweb could load it and processing it?

Thanks
Bromo

Comment: Dear all, no need to answer this question, I already figure it out, on how to extend mochiweb, and add custom config for start up the server.

Comment: If anybody can delete this thread ... welcome.

Comment: You should write an answer with the solution and upvote and accept it: this way others can learn from your effort! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did, was:

1. I create a new folder inside priv, called: config
2. I put my config file there
3. I add a line inside **mochiweb_sup.erl** like below, to put my config folder as part of the parameters that will be passed to **mochiweb_web.erl** module:

   ```
   web_spec(Mod, Port) ->
       WebConfig = [{ip, {0,0,0,0},
                    {port, Port},
                    %% my code is below
                    {docroot, something_deps:local_path(["priv", "www"])},
                    {custom_config, something_deps:local_path(["priv", "config"])}],
   ...
   ```
4. Than I read that additional path from **mochiweb_web.erl** module like below

   ```
   start(Options) ->
       {DocRoot, Options1} = get_option(docroot, Options),
       %% my code is below
       {ConfigPath, Options2} = get_option(custom_config, Options1),

       %% loading my config file
       {ok, FileHandler} = get_config_file(ConfigPath),
   ...
   ```
5. Then I load my custom config file by creating a function as below:

   ```
   get_config_file(ConfigPath) ->
       FileName = "custom_config.txt",
       case file:consult(filename:join([ConfigPath, FileName])) of
           {ok, FileHandler} ->
               {ok, FileHandler};
           {error, Reason} ->
               {error, Reason}
       end.
   ```

That's it! now you can further process that config file as you like.
If you want to process the config, I suggest you to process it inside the **start(Options)** block, and before **mochiweb_http:start** function executed, so if you need to pass the result, you can pass it as part of the arguments in **mochiweb_http:start**, but that means you need to extend the **mochiweb_http:start** function in **mochiweb_http.erl** module.

Thanks.